# How to create a custom shape of a button but keep it clickable and focusable

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I want to make a button to have a custom shape, but when I tried the shape changed, but it wasn't clickable/focusable, how do I do it?

Comment: did you try using ImageButton, or custom drawables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for, but I have done this a couple times where I liked a rounded button a little bit more, or if it's a widget, I wanted a checkbox.  Here's a couple examples I just did by just changing android:background:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/widget_yes_no_checkbox_off"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkbox_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/checkbox_size"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/right_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"
           />
```

This gave me a button that looks like a checkbox (necessary for making a checkbox in a widget).

Or, here's a drawable xml to help me round a button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="@color/primaryDarkColor"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

with it's corresponding style theme:

```
 <style name="myAppStyle.ButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_button</item>
    </style>
```

So, in summary, I think the easiest way to do this is to still do a button layout, but use the background attribute to change the way your button looks.

Comment: Any luck with your button background?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways,

1. Set any layout/button with shape drawable and add         `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` in XML
2. Set the Style attribute in button.
   `style="@style/buttonTheme"` in its XML and define
   `<style name="buttonTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
       <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/#000000</item>` in /style folder.